# Template pgettext-like tag

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates

In Django templates there is a `{% trans %}` tag for intenationalizing templates. It behaves like `ugettext()` function.

Is there also a tag behaving like `pgettext()` in django templates, where I can specify message context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is, but it'll be in the upcoming Django 1.4 or you can try it by using Django development version.

The tag works like this:

```
{% trans "Hello" context "greeting" %}
```